# Descripency in extracting the Specification Part in particular site

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

```
Option Explicit
Private MB As Selenium.ChromeDriver
Sub Test()
Dim i As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastrow
Dim MyURL As String
MyURL = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
Set MB = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
MB.Start
MB.Get MyURL
MB.Wait 10000
Dim specs As Selenium.WebElements
Dim values As Selenium.WebElements
Dim j As Long
Set specs = MB.FindElementsByCss("[data-testid='product-techs'] dt")
Set values = MB.FindElementsByCss("[data-testid='product-techs'] dd")
For j = 1 To 1
On Error GoTo Last
Sheet1.Cells(i, "B").Value = Join$(Array(specs.Item(j).Text, values.Item(j).Text), ":")
Next
For j = 1 To 2
On Error GoTo Last
Sheet1.Cells(i, "C").Value = Join$(Array(specs.Item(j).Text, values.Item(j).Text), ":")
Next
For j = 1 To 3
On Error GoTo Last
Sheet1.Cells(i, "D").Value = Join$(Array(specs.Item(j).Text, values.Item(j).Text), ":")
Next
For j = 1 To 4
On Error GoTo Last
Sheet1.Cells(i, "E").Value = Join$(Array(specs.Item(j).Text, values.Item(j).Text), ":")
Next
For j = 1 To 5
On Error GoTo Last
Sheet1.Cells(i, "F").Value = Join$(Array(specs.Item(j).Text, values.Item(j).Text), ":")
Next
For j = 1 To 6
On Error GoTo Last
Sheet1.Cells(i, "G").Value = Join$(Array(specs.Item(j).Text, values.Item(j).Text), ":")
Next
For j = 1 To 7
On Error GoTo Last
Sheet1.Cells(i, "H").Value = Join$(Array(specs.Item(j).Text, values.Item(j).Text), ":")
Next
For j = 1 To 8
On Error GoTo Last
Sheet1.Cells(i, "I").Value = Join$(Array(specs.Item(j).Text, values.Item(j).Text), ":")
Next
For j = 1 To 9
On Error GoTo Last
Sheet1.Cells(i, "J").Value = Join$(Array(specs.Item(j).Text, values.Item(j).Text), ":")
Next
For j = 1 To 10
On Error GoTo Last
Sheet1.Cells(i, "K").Value = Join$(Array(specs.Item(j).Text, values.Item(j).Text), ":")
Next
If i = lastrow Then
MB.Quit
End If
Next i
Last: Exit Sub
End Sub
```

In here, I was trying to extract the specification part of some of the weblinks. For the first 2 links it has only only 10 "label & values" so, all got extracted, but in the case 3rd link, it has more that 10 "label & values" which didn't got extracted. I need to correct the above code in such a way that, how much ever the number of "label & values" web link may may contain, it should extract all of it.

1st Link : https://www.grainger.com/product/SALISBURY-Blanket-Canister-Orange-3KUX9
2nd Link : https://www.grainger.com/product/SALISBURY-Blanket-Clamp-Pin-Yellow-5ZV66
3rd Link : https://www.grainger.com/product/SCHNEIDER-ELECTRIC-IEC-Supplementary-Protector-482N41

Please advise on how we can alter this to get it done. I tried that with below alteration...
For j = 1 To specs.Count
On Error GoTo Last
Sheet1.Cells(i, "B").Value = Join$(Array(specs.Item(j).Text, values.Item(j).Text), ":")
Next
But, it is extracting only the last label & value in the list instead of all. Kindly help me out with this.

Answer (score 1):

Simply loop over the number of items in `specs` (or `values`). You can check the number of items by using the `Count`-property.

You can speed up your code by setting a Timeout for your driver with     `MB.Timeouts.ImplicitWait = 10`. This will wait a maximum of 10 seconds, but if the data is loaded, the code will continue to run.

Have a look to the following routine:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim MB As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    MB.Timeouts.ImplicitWait = 10
    MB.Start
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, row As Long, lastRow As Long, col As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    row = 2
    lastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    
    For row = 2 To lastRow
        ' Read Web page
        Dim MyURL As String
        MyURL = ws.Cells(row, 1)
        MB.Get MyURL

        ' Get values
        Dim specs As Selenium.WebElements
        Dim values As Selenium.WebElements
        Set specs = MB.FindElementsByCss("[data-testid='product-techs'] dt")
        Set values = MB.FindElementsByCss("[data-testid='product-techs'] dd")
    
        ' Write all values to Excel
        For col = 1 To specs.Count
            ws.Cells(row, col + 1).Value = specs.Item(col).Text & ":" & values.Item(col).Text
        Next col
    Next row
    
    MB.Quit
End Sub
```